# Travis/Coverity integration: YAML encoding issue

Tags: github, yaml, travis-ci, coverity

I've been using the following `.travis.yml` file for configuring Travis CI for my project.

```
language: c
compiler:
  - clang
  - gcc
env:
  - memcheck=yes optimize=yes
  - memcheck=yes optimize=no
  - memcheck=no optimize=yes
  - memcheck=no optimize=no
install: sudo make install
script: make test
```

I'm now trying to integrate Travis with Coverity, as described [here](https://scan.coverity.com/travis_ci). However, the YAML file I have created isn't well-formed.

```
language: c
compiler:
  - clang
  - gcc
env:
  global:
    - secure: someLongTokenHere
  - memcheck=yes optimize=yes
  - memcheck=yes optimize=no
  - memcheck=no optimize=yes
  - memcheck=no optimize=no
addons:
  coverity_scan:
    project:
      name: standage/AEGeAn
      description: Build submitted via Travis CI
    notification_email: daniel.standage@gmail.com
    build_command_prepend: make clean
    build_command: make test
    branch_pattern: covscan
install: sudo make install
script: make test
```

The problem is with the `env` block. How can I define the `env::global::secure` variable as required by Coverity but still define my build matrix as I had done previously, all in [valid YAML](https://lint.travis-ci.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Some more Googling finally turned up something useful: see [this tweet](https://twitter.com/travisci/status/543394550950408192) and links therein.

It turns out you can use `env::matrix` to define a build matrix if you need to use `env::global` for Coverity Scan configuration. This is valid YAML (at least as determined by Travis' parser) and solves the aforementioned configuration problem.

```
language: c
compiler:
  - clang
  - gcc
env:
  global:
    - secure: someLongTokenHere
  matrix:
    - memcheck=yes optimize=yes
    - memcheck=yes optimize=no
    - memcheck=no optimize=yes
    - memcheck=no optimize=no
addons:
  coverity_scan:
    project:
      name: standage/AEGeAn
      description: Build submitted via Travis CI
    notification_email: daniel.standage@gmail.com
    build_command_prepend: make clean
    build_command: make test
    branch_pattern: covscan
install: sudo make install
script: make test
```